# How can I use a Tumblr photoset with the Twitter gallery card?

Tags: tumblr, twitter-card

I'm trying to use Twitter's gallery card to show off a Tumblr photoset.  This is the relvant portion of the code, and everything validates just fine with Twitter:

```
        {block:Photoset}
            <meta name="twitter:card" content="gallery">
            {block:Photos}<meta name="twitter:image" content="{PhotoURL-500}"/>{/block:Photos}
            {block:Photos}<meta name="twitter:image0" content="{PhotoURL-500}"/>{/block:Photos} 
            {block:Photos}<meta name="twitter:image1" content="{PhotoURL-500}"/>{/block:Photos} 
            {block:Photos}<meta name="twitter:image2" content="{PhotoURL-500}"/>{/block:Photos}
            {block:Photos}<meta name="twitter:image3" content="{PhotoURL-500}"/>{/block:Photos}
            {block:Caption}<meta name="twitter:title" content="Photo Gallery"/>{/block:Caption}
        {/block:Photoset}
```

However, if you look closely you may see my problem.  I can't figure out how to get unique URLs to each image.  {PhotoURL-500} always just returns the same image.  According to my apparently incorrect reading of the Tumblr docs (http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photoset-posts) it seems like {block:Photos} within {block:Photoset} should cycle through.

What am I missing?

Also - yes, I'm aware I've hard coded the content for twitter:Title.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible as of right now.

The issue is that `{block:Photos}` will iterate over each photo and render the markup inside that tag, but you can't manually control that to pinpoint a single photo.

What your code is doing is that for each photo it renders the Twitter markup 4 times; it wouldn't be a problem if Twitter accepted multiple images without requiring them to be explicitly declared like `image0`, `image1`, etc like [OpenGraph](http://ogp.me/#array) does (what you want is possible with OpenGraph, just put a single meta tag in a Photos block and it'll be rendered for each photo), but looking at how Twitter is being more and more hostile towards developers leaves little hope for a fix on their side.